# How to know when socket.io.emit() is finished with sending out data

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I am sending large amount of data(video stream) to clients with socket.io. I use node.js + socket.io on the server side and a simple socket.io client on the client side(browser).

Now I need a control mechanism that does not send out data too fast (otherwise the server will crash due to overflow). The socket.io API/reference is very spare in my oppinion, the only thing I could find was [Acknowledgments in socket.io](http://socket.io/docs/#sending-and-getting-data-(acknowledgements)). But this won't do, because I am streaming to several clients. Is there any way to tell how many bytes were sent over socket.emit() or a simple "true" when the emit is finnished sending out data?

Note again that this does not work because I am streaming to several clients:

```
io.emit('newmessage',buffer2,callbackfunction);
```

Comment: Instead of emit, you could use a loop over each client and have an individual callback for each client

Comment: Actually I am losing confidence that I can even do this with socket.io. 
I have problems sending out 100*100*4 bytes to a single client with 30fps

Comment: That's about 1.15MB/s of data. That should still be do-able with socket.io, though einaros/ws does have better overall performance